# How to render a registered trademark in superscript

Tags: ios, objective-c, unicode, uilabel

if I have a paragraph of text in `UILabel` and I need to display a registered trademark in the middle of the text, how should I implement it? I don't really want to use an image view.  I kind of think to override `drawRect` or sth but haven't figured it out yet.

Thanks!

Comment: @MattBall, “™” is TRADEMARK SIGN. The symbol for *registered* trademark is REGISTERED SIGN “®” U+00AE.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I was not clear as to which the OP actually meant. Either way, the suggestion stands.

Comment: my question is how to display the symbol ® in superscript. I don't have problem displaying symbol ™

Answer (score 5):

You can use the Unicode character sequence `\u2122` anywhere within an `NSString` and it will be rendered appropriately by a `UILabel`:

```
someLabel.text = @"This is some text about a Trademarked Name\u2122";
```

Comment: Or you could make this readable and type in the `™` character directly. `someLabel.text = @"This is some text about a Trademarked Name™";`

Answer (score 2):

It's unicode as Matt suggested. This is simply how you would use it in an NSLocalizedString. Unicode represents [symbols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters). NSLocalizedStrings are the recommended practice when dealing with strings to support multiple languages using language files.

```
someText.text = NSLocalizedString(@"iPhone\u2122",nil);
```

Comment: Please explain. What is this? and why use it?

Comment: It's unicode as Matt suggested. This is simply how you would use it in an NSString. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters

Comment: There is no need for `stringWithFormat`. Please don't use `stringWithFormat` unless the string actually has format specifiers that need to be replaced with values.

Comment: Correct rmaddy, and you should also be using NSLocalizedString for best practice or define it elsewhere... I think he got the point.

Comment: @MarkM I was going more for could you please explain in your answer not comments, just having a line of code isn't a very good answer. What would you like me to do with this code? Why use this over the others? etc. Answers are good when they have explanations with them. I am tempted to downvote this because there is no explanation, please correct and I won't

Comment: @MarkM better +1 for the edit, but I was wondering now why would you need to use `NSLocalizedString` could you not just do it the way jszumski has done it?

Comment: Popeye, please offer an answer to the question rather than questioning other answers with a down vote threat... Your comments bring no value to the conversation although an answer would. Please offer an answer if you have a better solution then let the author decide the best solution. We are here to contribute, not to criticize. As I mentioned in my post, using NSLocalizedStrings is the recommended way to handle strings in iOS as supporting multiple languages is very common and highly recommended by Apple therefore a good habit to get in although not required.

Comment: @MarkM Why offer a solution when there are already 3 solution that all say the same thing. All I was trying to do was help you improve your answer as just showing some code doesn't help anyone, so maybe you should have a read of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer

Comment: I appreciate your editing capabilities of my link although I find your questioning non-condusive to this question/answer. Let the author ask the questions please. You have made your point as have I.

Comment: @MarkM I wasn't trying to offend and I am sorry if I did, it's just answers that just show code and don't have an explanation normally get downvoted, and my inquiry after that was an actual inquiry of why to help myself as I wouldn't normally add the `NSLocalizedString`. This site is all about helping each other so if someone else asks you in the comments it would be nice (all though not required) to help them as well its not just about the person who has asked the question its about a community helping each other. Like I say I am sorry if I offend you.

Comment: And I too am sorry if I sounded defensive. It just appears too often on SO that people come in, edit a question, ask a question, yet never provide useful information pertaining to the question. I agree a detailed response is much more useful to an end user although time restraints make this unpractical until time allows for further editing. And to clarify, my original answer did not only provide code.  Perhaps an explanation as to why not use stringWithFormat is also in order?

Answer (score 2):

Use the character REGISTERED SIGN “®” U+00AE (written inside a string literal as `\00AE` if you cannot type it directly). Note that its appearance varies by font: generally, it looks like a superscript, but this is not a requirement, and some fonts show it on text baseline with with the “R” about half the size of a regular “R”, making it rather readable.

Comment: Thanks but I am looking for a way to display the symbol in superscript programatically - don't really want to use multiple labels...

Answer (score 2):

From iOS6> we can use NSAttributedString concept. Please see the below code snippet. Please ignore if anyone already aware of this.

```
static NSString *html =
    @"<html>"
    "  <body>Here is trademark &reg; </i></body>"
    "</html>";

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 280, 300, 200)];
    NSError *err = nil;
    label.attributedText =
    [[NSAttributedString alloc]
     initWithData: [html dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
     options: @{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType }
     documentAttributes: nil
     error: &err];
    if(err)
        NSLog(@"Unable to parse label text: %@", err);
```